# snd_hda_intel fails to load and black screen after delay

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, systemd-logind

two days ago I `modprobe -r snd_hda_intel` and `modprobe` it back. Today I got a black screen after a certain delay when loading `lightdm`.

Here's the message in dmesg:

```
[...]
[ 47.313515] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Start delayed initialization
[ 47.418106] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[ 47.418220] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no AFG or MFG node found
[ 47.418299] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no AFG or MFG node found
[ 47.418352] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no AFG or MFG node found
[ 47.418380] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no AFG or MFG node found
[ 47.418403] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs initialized
[ 47.418425] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: initialization error
[ 53.195954] systemd-logind[1060]: Failed to start unit user@1000.service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[ 53.195961] systemd-logind[1060]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[...]
```

Adding `sleep 10` before `exec lightdm` seems to have fixed it, but the message are still there.

I'm using kubuntu 14.10.

A rather long kind of related post can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246301&page=2